# Getting the Number that an Object is located in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`s, one contains the letters a - z, the other has for example, the letters a, b, and c. How do I find, for example, the index in the ArrayList that "b" is at (which in this case is 1)?

here's an example of code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ARRAYLETTERS = new ArrayList<String>();

ARRAYLETTERS.add("a");
ARRAYLETTERS.add("b");
ARRAYLETTERS.add("c");

//now I need to get the number spot that b is at (1)
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
int position = ARRAYLETTERS.indexOf("a");
```

As an aside, you really should stick to standard java naming conventions and use camel case (`arrayLetters`) instead of all-caps for member names.

Comment: Thanks! That'll do it then!

Answer (score 1):

You use `ARRAYLETTERS.indexOf("b")`.

Answer (score 1):

use [ArrayList.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))  to get get index of object.
eg:

```
int index=ARRAYLETTERS.indexOf("b");
```

Comment: Please can you explain what this answer adds, that was not present in the two earlier answers?

Comment: @DavidWallace How about a link to the relevant method?

Comment: Right.  Because using google to find information on the internet would be such a counter-intuitive thing to do.  It's bad enough to make Stack Overflow into a copy of the Javadocs.  It's much worse to copy it three times.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did not find any answer while I was posting my answer but I have added link to API so that user would understand it more clearly.